# "Question couldn't be submitted" and "Question is ready to publish" icons aren't aligned with background color in Dark Mode

Tags: bug, design, dark-mode, ask-question-form

Got this error in the Ask Question page, and saw that the error icon wasn't aligned with the red background:

[image]

Same thing with the green icon:

[image]

It looks okay in the normal mode, like a red shadow, but here it looks like a mistake.